# Error when trying to use imported Sass variables

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using the Live Sass Compiler extension for VSCode. I have set it up so that it outputs the css in a separate file.

When done compiling it throws the following error (same with @import instead of @use):

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...und-color: base": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$primary-color;"
        on line 5 of sass/.......\test.scss
>>   background-color: base.$primary-color;
   ------------------------^
```

My directory:

```
│   index.html
│
├───css
│       test.css
│       test.css.map
│
└───scss
        test.scss
        _base.scss
```

Sass version:

```
$ sass --version
1.38.0 compiled with dart2js 2.13.4
```

_base.scss:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

styles.scss:

```
@use 'base';

.inverse {
  background-color: base.$primary-color;
  color: white;
}
```

Any ideas on what's causing this error?

Comment: just `@import variables` and then use no need to add `@use etc`. After importing `.inverse { background-color: $primary-color; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@import` instead of `@use` and refer to `$primary-color` directly like this:

```
@import 'base';
.inverse {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  color: white;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Please note the @import rule has been deprecated and will be [removed](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)